# How to start mongo on debian Debian 8.1

Tags: mongodb, debian, mongo-shell

I have debian os installed on my computer.

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)
Release:    8.1
Codename:   jessie
```

I have followed this toturial to [Install MongoDB on Debian](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) install mongo db on my computer.

Mongodb version:

```
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
```

Now when I run `mongo` command to terminal, It says

```
mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
2015-08-08T06:29:50.480-0500 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-08-08T06:29:50.481-0500 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

And running this command show below error

```
sudo service mongodb restart
Failed to restart mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The `mongod` daemon is clearly not running. Check your service configuration. It is either called `mongodb` (which it seems not to be) or `mongod`. Then check the configuration files as referenced in the service script for locations of data and logs to see any errors presented.

Answer (score 3):

Just met a similar problem on a Debian Jessie.

For me, the following error on startup

> Failed to restart mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service

was due to an previous mongodb installation that replaced **/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service** with a symlink to **/dev/null**. Check it with **ls -l**.

Otherwise, your problem can be due to limited space storage, bad permissions folders or bad journal configuration file size. Try running the server process manually with

> /usr/bin/mongod start

and have a look on standard output. Usually explicit errors appear this way.

Comment: thanks dude, you really help me, It's exactly what happened here!